# how to combine these multiple queries in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, postgresql

How to combine these queries in laravel. Please help me, thanks a lot

```
$keyTitleUnique = Setting::where('key', 'title')->first();
$keyDescriptionUnique = Setting::where('key', 'description')->first();
$keyUnique = Setting::where('key', $request->key)->first();
```

i need ouput:
[image]

Comment: not sure if this is what u want to achieve. edit the question to make clear what u want to achieve - `Setting::where('key', 'title')->orWhere('key', 'description')->orWhere('key', $request->key)->first();`

Comment: how to if i want check record exits?

Comment: store it into a variable and check if it is not null. alternatively u can use [firstOrFail](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrFail) instead of `first` - will throw a 404 if is not found

Comment: `Setting::whereIn('key', ['title', 'description', $request->key])->get();` ...